# Read from a Single Table and write it to different database tables using spring batch

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am kind of new to spring batch processing. I want to have the following functionality-

1. Read from a single table of Mysql Database.
2. Call the item processor which will parse the data into 5 different objects.
3. Call Item writer to write these 5 objects to 5 different tables ( condition is the id returned after the first insert from first object is used for the second object in the table data).

How can I achieve this using Spring batch, is there any alternate approach which I can use to increase the performance and get the functionality? 
Any Help will be appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: You can refer to https://bigzidane.wordpress.com/2016/09/16/spring-batch-multiple-writers/ and customize it for you. If you can't , please let me know, I will write an example for you.

Comment: And another thing is if you think of performance, please apply Partitioner level.

Comment: @NghiaDo I am Naive in this. Can I get an example for this. Reading and Writing to the database with the above scenario. Thanks!!!

Comment: Step 1 and 2 are really easy to achive and you can solve by yourself, just do more pratice with SB. When you have some code to show us and a real problem (not just a generic "how to...") came back and we will be happy to help us.